# Did Nolan leave the ending of Inception up to the audience?

Tags: plot-explanation, inception

I know that a lot of discussion about this one has taken place already. But as you know its "INCEPTION"! every time you see it, it blows your mind...
        So if you see closely you can see that in the last couple seconds of movie the totum trembles and the moment we think its going to fall down Nolan ended the scene. So here, was Nolan trying to suggest that everyone can decide there own version? Either you can think that the totum kept spinning and Cobb is stuck in limbo or the totum stopped spinning and Cobb is really back home.
        Any thoughts???

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the ending of Inception is open to viewer's interpretation. Check [this](http://www.wired.co.uk/magazine/archive/2011/01/play/inception-director-lives-the-dream) interview by Chris Nolan. About the open ending Nolan says that

> I've always believed that if you make a film with ambiguity, it needs
>   to be based on a true interpretation. If it's not, then it will
>   contradict itself, or it will be somehow insubstantial and end up
>   making the audience feel cheated. Ambiguity has to come from the
>   inability of the character to know -- and the alignment of the
>   audience with that character.

As for Nolan's own interpretation he stated

> I choose to believe that Cobb gets back to his kids, because I have
>   young kids. People who have kids definitely read it differently than
>   those who don't. Clearly the audience brings a lot to it. **The most
>   important emotional thing about the top spinning at the end is that
>   Cobb is not looking at it. He doesn't care.**